# Javascript function working strangely during the first call in CHROME?

Tags: javascript

HI all,

Below mentioned javascript code works fine in all browsers including chrome(from second call onwards).

```
function call(val){
        url = window.location.href;
        indexnum = url.lastIndexOf("/");
        str = url.slice(indexnum+1);
        window.location.href = url.replace(str, "sample.php?src_q=") + val;
    }
```

I am calling this function on onclick of a link as below

```
<?php  echo "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:call(\"$fieldvalue\");'>$fieldvalue</a>"  ?>
```

Normal Behaviour : In all browser after clicking on the link new formed url is

url://localhost/mysite/sample.php?src_q=val

Strange Behaviour : When I click on the link for the first time in chrome value of variable `val` gets replaced by url and its value as follows

http://localhost/mysite/sample.php?src_q=http://localhost/mysite/val

This strange behaviour happens during the first click in chrome. From the second call onwards in the same tab, the value of variable `val` works fine and I get desired url.

I tried to google on it, but couldn't found any explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function you're calling and the function you posted don't match...is this the right function and just a question error, or other way around?

Comment: Also: get rid of that "javascript:" prefix from your "onclick" attribute. It is unnecessary. (Nothing to do with your problem, however.)

Comment: Also, single quoted HTML attributes are invalid

Comment: @kibibu: No they're not. They're invalid in *XHTML*. In HTML you can use single quotes or double quotes or (if the attribute value has only certain characters in it) no quotes at all. See the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Right you are. It truly surprises me that they kept that in HTML5. I much prefer the XHTML approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Drop the "javascript:" from the beginning of the `onclick`. You'd use that in an `href`, not in an `onclick`.
2. You might want to cancel navigation when the user clicks the link, by returning `false`:

   ```
   onclick='callSearch2(...); return false;'
   ```